# Dealing with NaN (missing) values for Logistic Regression- Best practices?

Tags: machine-learning, nan, logistic-regression, missing-data, data-cleaning

I am working with a data-set of patient information and trying to calculate the Propensity Score from the data using MATLAB. After removing features with many missing values, I am still left with several missing (NaN) values.

I get errors due to these missing values, as the values of my cost-function and gradient vector become NaN, when I try to perform logistic regression using the following Matlab code (from Andrew Ng's Coursera Machine Learning class) :

```
[m, n] = size(X);
X = [ones(m, 1) X];    
initial_theta = ones(n+1, 1);
[cost, grad] = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y);
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);

[theta, cost] = ...
    fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

Note: sigmoid and costfunction are working functions I created for overall ease of use.

The calculations can be performed smoothly if I replace all NaN values with 1 or 0. However I am not sure if that is the best way to deal with this issue, and I was also wondering what replacement value I should pick (in general) to get the best results for performing logistic regression with missing data. **Are there any benefits/drawbacks to using a particular number (0 or 1 or something else) for replacing the said missing values in my data?**

Note: I have also normalized all feature values to be in the range of 0-1.

Any insight on this issue will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It seems a general question, not Matlab related. Maybe you can get more insights by not restricting yourself to Matlab?

Comment: @matanj Good point. I am changing it now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out earlier, this is a generic problem people deal with regardless of the programming platform. It is called "missing data imputation".

Enforcing all missing values to a particular number certainly has drawbacks. Depending on the distribution of your data it can be drastic, for example, setting all missing values to 1 in a binary sparse data having more zeroes than ones.

Fortunately, MATLAB has a function called `knnimpute` that estimates a missing data point by its closest neighbor.

From my experience, I often found `knnimpute` useful. However, it may fall short when there are too many missing sites as in your data; the neighbors of a missing site may be incomplete as well, thereby leading to inaccurate estimation. Below, I figured out a walk-around solution to that; it begins with imputing the least incomplete columns, (optionally) imposing a safe predefined distance for the neighbors. I hope this helps.

```
function data = dnnimpute(data,distCutoff,option,distMetric)
% data = dnnimpute(data,distCutoff,option,distMetric)
%
%   Distance-based nearest neighbor imputation that impose a distance
%     cutoff to determine nearest neighbors, i.e., avoids those samples 
%     that are more distant than the distCutoff argument.
%
%   Imputes missing data coded by "NaN" starting from the covarites 
%     (columns) with the least number of missing data. Then it continues by 
%     including more (complete) covariates in the calculation of pair-wise 
%     distances.
%
%   option, 
%       'median'      - Median of the nearest neighboring values
%       'weighted'    - Weighted average of the nearest neighboring values
%       'default'     - Unweighted average of the nearest neighboring values
%
%   distMetric,
%       'euclidean'   - Euclidean distance (default)
%       'seuclidean'  - Standardized Euclidean distance. Each coordinate
%                       difference between rows in X is scaled by dividing
%                       by the corresponding element of the standard
%                       deviation S=NANSTD(X). To specify another value for
%                       S, use D=pdist(X,'seuclidean',S).
%       'cityblock'   - City Block distance
%       'minkowski'   - Minkowski distance. The default exponent is 2. To
%                       specify a different exponent, use
%                       D = pdist(X,'minkowski',P), where the exponent P is
%                       a scalar positive value.
%       'chebychev'   - Chebychev distance (maximum coordinate difference)
%       'mahalanobis' - Mahalanobis distance, using the sample covariance
%                       of X as computed by NANCOV. To compute the distance
%                       with a different covariance, use
%                       D =  pdist(X,'mahalanobis',C), where the matrix C
%                       is symmetric and positive definite.
%       'cosine'      - One minus the cosine of the included angle
%                       between observations (treated as vectors)
%       'correlation' - One minus the sample linear correlation between
%                       observations (treated as sequences of values).
%       'spearman'    - One minus the sample Spearman's rank correlation
%                       between observations (treated as sequences of values).
%       'hamming'     - Hamming distance, percentage of coordinates
%                       that differ
%       'jaccard'     - One minus the Jaccard coefficient, the
%                       percentage of nonzero coordinates that differ
%       function      - A distance function specified using @, for
%                       example @DISTFUN.
%  
if nargin < 3
    option = 'mean';
end
if nargin < 4
    distMetric = 'euclidean';
end

nanVals = isnan(data);
nanValsPerCov = sum(nanVals,1);
noNansCov = nanValsPerCov == 0;
if isempty(find(noNansCov, 1))
    [~,leastNans] = min(nanValsPerCov);
    noNansCov(leastNans) = true;
    first = data(nanVals(:,noNansCov),:);
    nanRows = find(nanVals(:,noNansCov)==true); i = 1;
    for row = first'
        data(nanRows(i),noNansCov) = mean(row(~isnan(row)));
        i = i+1;
    end
end

nSamples = size(data,1);
if nargin < 2
    dataNoNans = data(:,noNansCov);
    distances = pdist(dataNoNans);
    distCutoff = min(distances);
end
[stdCovMissDat,idxCovMissDat] = sort(nanValsPerCov,'ascend');
imputeCols = idxCovMissDat(stdCovMissDat>0);
% Impute starting from the cols (covariates) with the least number of 
% missing data. 
for c = reshape(imputeCols,1,length(imputeCols))    
    imputeRows = 1:nSamples;
    imputeRows = imputeRows(nanVals(:,c));   
    for r = reshape(imputeRows,1,length(imputeRows))
        % Calculate distances
        distR = inf(nSamples,1);
        %
        noNansCov_r = find(isnan(data(r,:))==0);
        noNansCov_r = noNansCov_r(sum(isnan(data(nanVals(:,c)'==false,~isnan(data(r,:)))),1)==0);
        %
        for i = find(nanVals(:,c)'==false)
            distR(i) = pdist([data(r,noNansCov_r); data(i,noNansCov_r)],distMetric);            
        end
        tmp = min(distR(distR>0));        
        % Impute the missing data at sample r of covariate c
        switch option
            case 'weighted'
                data(r,c) = (1./distR(distR<=max(distCutoff,tmp)))' * data(distR<=max(distCutoff,tmp),c) / sum(1./distR(distR<=max(distCutoff,tmp)));
            case 'median'
                data(r,c) = median(data(distR<=max(distCutoff,tmp),c),1);
            case 'mean'
                data(r,c) = mean(data(distR<=max(distCutoff,tmp),c),1);
        end
        % The missing data in sample r is imputed. Update the sample 
        % indices of c which are imputed. 
        nanVals(r,c) = false;  
    end    
    fprintf('%u/%u of the covariates are imputed.\n',find(c==imputeCols),length(imputeCols));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with missing data you can use one of the following three options:

- If there are not many instances with missing values, you can just delete the ones with missing values.
- If you have many features and it is affordable to lose some information, delete the entire feature with missing values.
- The best method is to fill some value (mean, median) in place of missing value. You can calculate the mean of the rest of the training examples for that feature and fill all the missing values with the mean. This works out pretty well as the mean value stays in the distribution of your data.

Note: When you replace the missing values with the mean, calculate the mean only using training set. Also, store that value and use it to change the missing values in the test set also.

If you use 0 or 1 to replace all the missing values then the data may get skewed so it is better to replace the missing values by an average of all the other values.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. That does make sense

Comment: @NadirN If you find the answer helpful you can accept it by ticking it.